# Blazor doesn't re-render on class change

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly

```
<div>
<div>
    <div class="@(Base64Images.Count == 0 ? "block" : "hidden")">
        <label for="file-upload">
            <span>Upload a file</span>

            <InputFile OnChange="HandleChange" id="file-upload" name="file-upload" class="sr-only" />
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="@(Base64Images.Count > 0 ? "block" : "hidden")">
        @foreach(var image in Base64Images)
        {
            <img src="@image" />
        }
    </div>
</div>
</div>

@code {
public IReadOnlyList<IBrowserFile> BrowserFiles { get; protected set; } = new List<IBrowserFile>();

private List<string> Base64Images { get; set; } = new List<string>();

private async Task<bool> HandleChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
{
    IReadOnlyList<IBrowserFile> fileList;

    BrowserFiles = new List<IBrowserFile> { e.File };

    await BrowserFilesToBase64Images();

    return true;
}

private async Task<bool> BrowserFilesToBase64Images()
{
    foreach(var image in BrowserFiles)
    {
        if(image != null)
        {
            var format = "image/png";
            var buffer = new byte[image.Size];
            await image.OpenReadStream().ReadAsync(buffer);
            Base64Images.Add($"data:{format};base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(buffer)}");
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

}

So I have this code, it's pretty simple. I want to display a preview of what the use uploads, but the preview must only be displayed after the file was selected. Likewise, I want to hide the input (but not remove it from the DOM) when there is an image loaded. But no matter what I do, Blazor won't re-render.

```
Base64Images.Count
```

Changes and I have been able to debug it. The conditions should be hit, but the HTML won't change. Is there any way to tell Blazor to re-render?

I know of `StateHasChanged()`, but not only that one is supposedly called in after every event, but even calling it multiple times doesn't force the re-render.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my test code based on what you've given us.  It works, so we're missing something obvious.

```
@page "/Images"

<div class="@(Base64Images.Count > 0 ? "block" : "hidden")">
    @foreach (var image in Base64Images)
    {
        <h4>Images goes here</h4>
        <img src="@image" />
    }

</div>

@if (!_hasImages)
{
<div>
    <InputFile OnChange="@OnInputFileChange" multiple />
</div>
}
else
{
    <div>
        @foreach (var image in Base64Images)
        {
            <h4>More Images goes here</h4>
            <img src="@image" />
        }
    </div>
}


<button class="btn btn-dark" @onclick="() => Click()"> Click</button>
@code {

    List<string> Base64Images = new List<string>();

    private bool _hasImages => Base64Images != null && Base64Images.Count > 0;

    void Click()
    {
        Base64Images.Add("Bye");
    }

    private async Task OnInputFileChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Base64Images.Add("Bye");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to explain what you want to happen.  You have `Lists`, but when you handle the `FileInput`'s `OnChange`, you're only getting one File (maybe).

If you want multiple files, then you'll have to set your FileInput like this:

```
<InputFile OnChange="HandleChange" id="file-upload" name="file-upload" class="sr-only" multiple />
```

And to get the collection of IBrowserFile objects, this:

```
BrowserFiles = e.GetMultipleFiles(maxAllowedFiles);
```